# How can I make Visual Studio 2012 break on Debug.Assert for a Windows Store application?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, assert

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and developing a Windows Store application. I have added some assertions using `Debug.Assert`.

When I run the application in the debugger, I want assertion failures to either throw exceptions or cause the debugger to break. However, they currently only output messages to the output window, which is barely useful to me.

**How can I cause the debugger to break or throw exceptions on assertion failures?**

I've considered using Code Contracts, but it significantly slows down my build times, so I don't want to use it.

I've tried `Contract.Assert`, but it produces a Windows desktop error message, which I don't see while the Windows Store application is full-screen.

I've also considered just throwing exceptions for developer assumptions/assertions, but I don't want this in the release code.